GridLayout CardView goes out of screen on my phone only
Im trying to make a list of products using GridLayout + CardView, it went well on the studio when i was designing Expected Results
But when i went ahead and opened the app on my phone i get this Results
this is my code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="Welcome $name"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp">
            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="4"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardElevation="0dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:contentDescription="evoo"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/extra_virgin_olive_oil" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Extra Virgin Olive Oil" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Extra virgin olive oil (EVOO) is processed from fruit of the olive (Olea europea..."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Rp. 100000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/premium_honey" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Premium Honey" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our premium honey is made from the nectar of flowers and collected by bees from..."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rp. 70000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/himalayan_pink_salt" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Himalayan Pink Salt" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our Himalayan pink salt is sourced from ancient salt mines in the Himalayan..."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rp.50000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/peanut" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Peanut" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Introducing our premium quality peanuts – the perfect snack for any occasion! Our..."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rp. 40000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/premium_green_tea" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Premium Green Tea" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our premium green tea is hand-picked and carefully selected to ensure the high..."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rp. 85000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/gourmet_popcorn" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Gourmet Popcorn" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our gourmet popcorn is made from the finest kernels and popped to perfection..."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rp. 35000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/organic_dark_chocolate" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Organic Dark Chocolate" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our organic dark chocolate is made from the finest cocoa beans and sweetened beans.."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rp. 70000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="140dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/organic_quinoa" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="Organic Quinoa" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our organic quinoa is a versatile and nutritious grain that is gluten-free and easy..."
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rp. 45000.00"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>
        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

I have tried messing around with the layout width/height changing it to wrap_content/match_parent but it still looks like that, i also have tried another post's answer which is changing the gridlayout orientation to horizontal but all it did was make the render worse after changing orientation to horizontal
